# Composer Full Disk Error When Only Half Full

Tags: php, composer-php

This is my first time using composer. I am trying to build a project that uses it but I cannot get composer to function properly. 
For the command composer diagnose I get the following every time:

```
PS C:\WinNMP\WWW\Oro> composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: WARNING
Defining autoload.psr-4 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance
License "Commercial" is not a valid SPDX license identifier, see https://spdx.org/licenses/ if you use an open license.
If the software is closed-source, you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: OK
Checking disk free space: FAIL
The disk hosting C:/Users/Mark/AppData/Roaming/Composer is full
```

All other tests return OK. My disk has 64gb free.
I tried searching for this issue but found little help. I upped the memory limit in php to 512mb as a shot in the dark without effect. Some posts related to this suggested it was out of memory but my ram never goes above 35% usage.

I tried running composer clear-cache without any effect.

Trying to run this on php 7.2.6, composer 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that triggers this error message is this:

```
private function checkDiskSpace($config)
{
    $minSpaceFree = 1024 * 1024;
    if ((($df = @disk_free_space($dir = $config->get('home'))) !== false && $df < $minSpaceFree)
        || (($df = @disk_free_space($dir = $config->get('vendor-dir'))) !== false && $df < $minSpaceFree)
    ) {
        return '<error>The disk hosting '.$dir.' is full</error>';
    }

    return true;
}
```

You may want to write a little script that makes the same check, except that without error suppression. To get the values for `home`and `vendor-dir` you can run these commands:

```
composer config home
composer config vendor-dir
```

A rough idea:

```
$home = trim(`composer config home`);
$vendorDir = trim(`composer config vendor-dir`);

var_dump($home, disk_free_space($home));
var_dump($vendorDir, disk_free_space($vendorDir));
```

Don't forget to make sure that you have full error reporting enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ran those commands and discovered that the vendor folder does not exist, triggering the error. Created it in the project root and the issue was solved